# node-qunit not working with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, qunit

I have installed node-qunit using npm and this appeared to work correctly.

The following script simply does nothing...no errors, no qunit output (not even failed test cases):

```
var testrunner = require('qunit');

testrunner.run({
   code: '/Users/macuser/Documents/test-input.js',
   tests: '/Users/macuser/Documents/test-cases.js'
}, function(report) {
   console.log(report);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of qunit you are using. I believe 0.2+ is unstable as it relies on Node 0.5+ (which is also unstable : http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-current-state-of-node-js/answer/Matt-Ranney)

See issue 31 https://github.com/kof/node-qunit/pull/31

Try installing the stable branch

```
npm install qunit@stable
```

Comment: How do I find this out? I installed it today using `npm install qunit`. How do I find out which version of node I am using? I believe that I should have 0.5.7 but I may be wrong. I just checked out the GIT repository and then configured and installed as instructed

Comment: I am using 0.5.7 (found via process.version) and have also tried using `npm install qunit@stable` but this doesn't appear to make any difference...nothing is getting output

Comment: Try `npm ls` to view the versions of each npm module. You might need to uninstall qunit `npm uninstall qunit` and reinstall.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and then installing the stable version, but this is not making any difference (to the problem). I have verified that it is a different version however.

Comment: It may be a bug with node 0.5.7, you may want to switch to 0.4.11 (the latest stable version of node). Also, 0.odd.x (0.1, 0.3, 0.5) versions of node are unstable, and 0.even.x (0.2, 0.4) are stable.

Comment: Thanks, Yep, must be a problem with 0.5.7 because it works now. I had to manually apply one bugfix that was applied to 0.5.x somewhere along the line, but it works